# Which types of GPS data (i.e., GGA, RMC, etc) are available only once a fix is obtained?

Tags: gps, nmea

In particular, which types have fix modes other than GGA? Which types provide data without a fix? What are parameters that make GGA and RMC stand out? What applications can depend only on GGA or RMC data?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "highest fix mode"?  Plenty of applications only need to know the current location.

Comment: @Brad My understanding is that GGA has a fix mode. What about the other types??? I’ll rephrase the question

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these three have: `GGA`, `GSA`, `RMC`.
Check [MathWorks 2020b Read and Parse NMEA Data Directly From GPS Receiver](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2020b/fusion/ug/read-and-parse-nmea-data-directly-from-gps-receiver.html).